# Can I start with multiple dots in a merit?

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, merits

I'm fairly certain starting merits aren't bought sequentially:

> Merit dots must be purchased sequentially with experience points. You have to buy • and then •• before your character can have ••• or more.

Conversely I assume when *not* spending experience points, you can jump to ••• if you spend three *points*.

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm mainly asking about the Professional Training merit, as it seems off for it not to be the case. BUt I figured it holds for everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not as you wrote it, but yes.**

You can devote three Merit *dots* at character creation to a scaled merit like Professional Training.

Comment: By points above I meant dots (as opposed to experience points).

Comment: @Pureferret Oh, I figured. But points and dots (and now, with GMC, beats and experiences) all mean different things. Just wanted to be clear.